# JObject does not contain a definition for 'user_name' and no accessible extension method 'user_name'

Tags: c#, function, api

Using C# for API and I'm just new to it and I can hardly understand the concepts I searched from the web. I badly need help for this error:

*'Object' does not contain a definition for 'user_name' and no accessible extension method 'user_name' accepting a first argument of type 'Object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Error occurs at lang.user_name and lang.address below. Here's the sample code:

```
public byte[] GenerateFile(List<UploadFileDataModel> uploadFile, string selectedLanguage)
        {
            int rowIndex = 1;
            IUserService serv = new UserService();
            JObject data = JObject.FromObject(new {
                user_name = "Username",
                address = "Address"
        });

            var lang = serv.GetCachedResourceValue(data, selectedLanguage);

           using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
           {
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Test";
                excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Test File";
                var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Test File");
                sheet.Name = "Test File";

                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, 1].Value = lang.user_name ;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, 2].Value = lang.address ;

                sheet.Cells.AutoFitColumns();
                return excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();
.....
            }
           }
```

Can someone enlighten me with this and what needs to be done? Thanks

Comment: `lang` is of type `JObject`. `JObject` doesn't have property called `user_name`

Comment: Hi @canton7, I've just updated the codes. Can't the properties be read inside of it? `JObject data = JObject.FromObject(new {  user_name = "Username", address = "Address" });`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get property `user_name` from object JObject. JObject does not have such property. Check it [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

Probably you should do something like:

```
var name = lang["user_name"];
```

Comment: Should I declare the properties one by one inside the JObject with var? like var name and var add? I'm sorry but I'm really confused. Hope you could enlighten me. Thanks

Comment: No, just are just supposed to use indexer: lang["property_name"] instead of lang.property_nam